# How to calculate t-values from percent ranks?

Tags: normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics

A norm-table from a psychological test is giving percent ranks (PR).

How can I transform those into t-values by calculation? (Assuming normal distribution.)

I found a lot of references on how to transform z --> t, but none on PR --> t.

Way back in university, we had tables with the bell-curve, to look up PR, z-values, t-values and stanines - but how to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Excel is available to you, you can use the `t.inv` and `norm.inv`functions. For the other direction (to get the probability from the t- or z-value), then use the `t.dist` and `norm.dist` functions. You'll get the same figures as with the tables.

**Edit:**

In PHP, this looks right:

- stats_cdf_normal (p, mean, sd, 1): returns float x which bounds cumulative probalility $p$
- stats_dens_normal (x , mean, sd): returns float cumulative probability

and

- stats_cdf_t (par1, par2, which): calculates any one parameter of the T distribution given values for the others.
- stats_dens_t (x, dfr)

This is all from http://php.net/manual/en/ref.stats.php

Comment: thanks for your advice! I do have excel, but would like to code a php-solution to be able to do this online.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you could ask to close this question (I'm told it's very important), and *migrate* it on another SE site... Maybe stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Comment: thanks, I'd like to leave it open, though, I still hope :-)

Comment: Do the functions from my last edit work? Can you try them?

Comment: wow!!! didn't think about that, thanks!!!